# TWIC holders skipping interview?

Tags: air-travel, usa, us-citizens, tsa, tsa-precheck

If I hold a [TWIC](http://www.tsa.gov/stakeholders/transportation-worker-identification-credential-twic%C2%AE) can TSA get my biological information from that for my Pre-check and allow me to skip the interview?

Answer (score 3):

According to UES who processes TWIC, Hazmat, and TSAPre applications, the TSA does not allow a connection between TWIC/Hazmat and TSAPre at this time.  Applicants who are seeking to enroll in TSAPre must still complete the in-person interview and fingerprinting as well as the FBI background check to get a Known Traveler Number (KTN) for TSAPre.

Source: Direct phone call to UES customer service

Edit:  The only official thing I can find is this: http://blog.tsa.gov/2011/10/how-to-sign-up-to-participate-in-tsa.html

> Sean said...
>
> Is there any value in possessing a TWIC card (Transporation Workers ID Credentialling) when it comes to expedited airport screening or registering/applying for Pre-check, GOES, etc? The DHS conducts a detailed background check and collects biometric data prior to issuing this security credential.

and

> Blogger Bob said...
>
> Sean - Not at this time. As with any pilot initiative, if proven successful, TSA will explore expanding the program to additional passengers, airports and airlines.
>
> Thanks,
>
> Blogger Bob
>      TSA Blog Team

You can however use a TWIC card as proof during enrollment: http://www.tsa.gov/tsa-precheck/required-documentation

Comment: Links would be helpful.

Comment: They don't have it officially published.  But there is plenty of people making comments on the official sites about the lack of consideration for TWIC.  My source would be a direct phone call to UES.  (As an aside, I would assume the O.P. wouldn't have asked if there was a link that was searchable)